# How to write a firebase rule to check access token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have the following rules setup for my firebase database:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to create a write rule that allows the user to write only if they have a valid access token. I don't think the above rule is correct, and I'm very confused as to how Firebase tracks user authorization.

This is how I've setup my application so far:

On the frontend (React), I have a simple email/password login component:

[image]

```
    axios.get('/auth', {
        headers: {
                username: this.usernameRef.current.value,
                password: this.passwordRef.current.value
            }
        }).then(...).catch(...);
```

My backend (Node.js/express) receives the request:

```
const fb = require('firebase');

const initFirebase = () => {
    const config = {
        apiKey: "***",
        authDomain: "***",
        databaseURL: "***",
        projectId: "***",
        storageBucket: "***",
        messagingSenderId: "***",
        appId: "***",
        measurementId: "***"
    };
    const app = fb.initializeApp(config);
    return app.firestore();
}

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const email = req.headers.username;
    const password = req.headers.password;

    let fbApp;
    if (!fb.apps.length) {
        try {
            initFirebase();
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).send('Error initializing Firebase.');
            return;
        }
    }
    fbApp = fb.apps[0];

    fbApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(user => {
        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(user));
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(401).send();
    });
});
```

If the request sent to Firebase to authenticate the user is successful, it returns a user object with an access token inside it. I return the user object to the frontend. The frontend stores the access token in localStorage and in the State. Then for any subsequent requests to firebase, it injects the token in the headers of the request.

For example, if I want to add a new post to my blog, I do it like this:

frontend:

```
            axios.post('/blogs', {
                title: this.state.newPost.title,
                body: this.state.newPost.body
            }, {
                headers: {Authorization: this.state.accessToken}
            }).then(response => {...}, err => {...});
```

The backend receives it and does this:

```
const fb = require('firebase');

const initFirebase = () => {
    const config = {
        apiKey: "***",
        authDomain: "***",
        databaseURL: "***",
        projectId: "***",
        storageBucket: "***",
        messagingSenderId: "***",
        appId: "***",
        measurementId: "***"
    };
    const app = fb.initializeApp(config);
    return app.firestore();
}

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.headers.authorization) {
        res.status(401).status('Unauthorized');
        return;
    }

    const chunks = [];
    req.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
    req.on('end', () => {
        const data = JSON.parse(chunks);
        const post = {};
        post.title = data.title;
        post.body = data.body;
        post.createdAt = Date.now();
        post.updatedAt = post.createdAt;

        let firestore;
        if (fb.apps.length) firestore = fb.apps[0].firestore();
        else {
            try {
                firestore = initFirebase();
            } catch (err) {
                res.status(500).send('Error initializing Firebase.');
                return; 
            }
        }

        firestore.collection('blogposts').add(post).then(docRef => {
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({id: docRef.id, createdAt: post.createdAt}));
        }).catch (err => {
            res.status(500).send('Error posting blog post.');
        });
    });
});
```

In simple use case scenarios, this works.

What I don't understand is how the security rules work on a per user basis. It seems that request.auth.uid (in the write rule above) is set so long as a user (any user) is authenticated.

I tried deleting the access token on the front end by deleting it from localStorage and the State, thereby mimicking the user not being logged in. Then I tried creating a new post. It worked. So Firebase obviously doesn't need me to send a valid access token for the write rule above to pass.

I tried creating a request to firebase directly from a completely different application (written in Node.js):

```
const fb = require('firebase');

const config = {
        apiKey: "***",
        authDomain: "***",
        databaseURL: "***",
        projectId: "***",
        storageBucket: "***",
        messagingSenderId: "***",
        appId: "***",
        measurementId: "***"
};
const store = fb.initializeApp(config).firestore();

const post = {
    title: 'blog #14',
    body: 'This is blog #14.',
    createdAt: Date.now(),
    updatedAt: Date.now()
}

store.collection('blogposts').add(post).then(docRef => {
    console.log('docRef.id = ',  docRef.id);
}).catch (err => {
    console.log('err=', err);
});
```

This failed with a PERMISSION_DENIED error from Firebase. This tells me the Firebase application created in initializeApp(...) must have something to do with it. My backend is re-using the same app for all requests, including the request to authenticate. This side application creates a whole new Firebase app. Is it the app which is keeping track of whether a user is authenticated or not? Does it keep a copy of the access token and implicitly send it with all requests to Firebase?

Oddly enough, this test seemed to de-authorize my main user. Back in the original application, I started getting the same PERMISSION_DENIED error. I had to delete the access token from localStorage, refresh the page, login again, and that seemed to reset it.

How would one write a Firebase rule that checks the access token? And how would I send the access token with requests to Firebase? If it's all in the Firebase app being used to make requests, how do I ensure a different app is used per person?

What would really help is a description of what the frontend is supposed to do to start the process (where the access token is sent if necessary), what the backend is supposed to do with this request, how the backend is supposed to call Firebase, and what the Firebase rule is supposed to look like.

Thanks so much for any forthcoming help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My backend is re-using the same app for all requests, including the request to authenticate.

This is the problem.  The client APIs you're using on the backend are just not meant to be used in the way that you're using them now on your backend.

Once you "sign in" the user to an instance of a FirebaseApp, that user is going to stay signed in until you tell it to sign out.  The backend is keeping the sign-in state, and refreshing the token, just like it would with a normal client app.  This means that your client's auth token is being disregarded after the sign-in, and therefore *you don't actually have a multi-user backend* (all requests are actually using the same user that was previously signed in).

Typically, Firebase client sign in on their own, and directly access Firestore data using the provided SDK, and that access is protected by security rules.  Most apps are built like this.

If you don't want to allow the client direct access to the database, you should instead:

- Sign in on the client directly using the Firebase Auth client SDK
- Pass the ID token to in each request to your API
- The backend should verify the token with the Firebase Admin SDK
- The backend can then make requests to Firestore using a server SDK, *but without the restriction of security rules*

If you go this route, security rules can no longer be used, since Firestore backend SDKs initialized with a service account always bypass rules.  The backend must know, using its own logic, if the user can access the data requested from the API.

The pattern you're looking for is shown in the documentation of the Firebase Admin SDK for [verifying ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

Comment: Thanks Doug. Based on your advice, I moved all the firebase logic to the frontend which seems to work. But one problem still remains. I can now see the firebase config file in the browser devTools (i.e. the file where I initialize the firebase app with the config settings). If I can see it, others can too. That means, they can setup a client app with those config settings and access my database. The write rule still prevents them from writing without being authenticated, but they can easily create new users and then sign in with them. Is there a way to hide the config file?

Comment: No, that's public information.  If this is a concern, tou might want to consider making the user go through some verification phase that can't be easily automated, and require that verification to be satisfied in order to make requests.